# PRESTASHOP 1.6 Display product category description on product list page

Tags: prestashop, categories

I have been trying to display my category description into the product listing page but can't crack it still.

I tried following codes and add it into my product-list.tpl;

```
($default_category->description)
```

AND

```
($product.default_category->description)
```

I understand that I need to modify the Product.php class function but I am not sure which one.
Can anyone guide me on this?

I had tried to modify getProductsProperties class by adding

```
$results_array = array(); 
$categories_ids = Product::getProductCategories($row['id_product']);
$categories_names = array();
foreach ($categories_ids AS $id) {
$category = new Category($id);
$categories_names[] = $category->getName();
}
$row['categories'] = $categories_names;
```

then add following codes to product-list.tpl but it didn't show anything.

```
<!-- Display categories -->
<span id="product_categories">
{foreach from=$product.categories item=category name=category}
{$category} <br/>
{/foreach}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this code to display current category

```
description:{$category->description}
```

Comment: Hi I tried the code, but only the 'description:' appears.

Answer (score 0):

description:{$category->description}

its definitely working Thanks @user2314737